# pig group by command don´t work

Tags: hadoop, group-by, cassandra, apache-pig, integrated

I installed Cassandra 2.0.7  and hadoop 2.3.0 on 3 nodes and pig 0.13.0  on one of the 3 nodes and I have table in cassandra as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sampletb (
  a text,
  b text,
  c text,
  d text,
  e int,
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c, d))
```

And I run the pig script in grunt as below:

```
rows = LOAD 'cql://db/ sampletb USING CqlStorage();

grouprows= group rows by ($0,$1);
```

when I run group it gives the following error:

> 2015-02-10 08:57:39,196 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.antlr.runtime.tree.BaseTree.insertChild(ILjava/lang/Object;)V
>   Details at logfile: /home/hadoopcluster/pig_1423545778153.log
>   The content of logfile is:

### Pig Stack Trace

> ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.antlr.runtime.tree.BaseTree.insertChild(ILjava/lang/Object;)V
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: >org.antlr.runtime.tree.BaseTree.insertChild(ILjava/lang/Object;)V
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.paren_expr(QueryParser.java:17532)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.cast_expr(QueryParser.java:17005)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.multi_expr(QueryParser.java:15679)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.expr(QueryParser.java:15568)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.real_arg(QueryParser.java:14634)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.join_group_by_clause(QueryParser.java:13663)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.group_item(QueryParser.java:8889)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.group_item_list(QueryParser.java:8721)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.group_clause(QueryParser.java:8611)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.op_clause(QueryParser.java:7047)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.general_statement(QueryParser.java:2314)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.statement(QueryParser.java:1579)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParser.query(QueryParser.java:395)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:236)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1684)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1657)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:600)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1069)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:228)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:203)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
>       at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:542)
>       at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

I searched a lot on the web but could not find any thing usefull please help urgently

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a class conflict. Make sure the used version of the antlr jar file matches the version required by pig.